# Advantages/Disadvantages of using int16 over int32

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

So, is there really any advantage to using int16? I can see how you might use it if you know your number is never going to use more than 16 bits. However, the compiler (as I understand it) optimizes for int (aka "int32") anyway. Also, it seems more common practice to use int, in the first place.

So, why would one use int16?

Comment: Because you you want to make sure the value will overflow properly... XD

Answer (score 5):

There are mainly two reasons that you might want to use `Int16` rather than `Int32`:

- You have a large array of them, and want to save some memory.
- You are interfacing with something else, that expects an `Int16`.

In normal code there is no good reason to prefer `Int16`. Using an `Int32` for example as a loop counter is faster, both in x86 mode and x64 mode. (An `Int32` is also faster than an `Int64` even in x64 mode.)

Comment: +1 for the loop counter, I didn't know that.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But, as you said, there normally isn't a reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

You use an `Int16` over `Int32`, when the numbers you are going to represent and make calculations with them etc. can be represented as `Int16`. In other words all depends on your data.

For instance, I have seen many people represent a 10 digit phone number as an `int`, which is an `Int32`. Usually we don't make any calculations with a phone number. Conceptually, it would be better if they had used a `string` for this purpose, or a `char[10]` instead of using an `int`. However, if they had done so, they would had seen any significant change.